# Problem updating files in htdocs folder of XAMPP server

Tags: php, xampp, opcache, htdocs

the htdocs folder (xampp) doesn't update the changes I make in the PHP file of the visual studio code, that is, I always need to make a copy and add it, can someone help me configure it to update automatically?

Comment: I guess the problem could be opcache. Try disabling it.

Comment: I did this: I changed the directory of the folder and deleted the cache memory and it worked. tks man

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem could be opcache. Try disabling it and I am sure the issue will disappear!